# How to get anchor tag in Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

Just a simple problem, I have used ajax to alert data which is echoed in PHP page. It is working fine except `href` link. a `href` link can't return, it returns whole code. For example, this is ajax code.

**form.html**

```
$("#ceb").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(returndata){
        alert(returndata);
     }
  });
  return false;
});
```

And this is php page **post.php**

```
echo "Thanks!, Please visit <a href='next.php'>this</a> page";
```

In alert window, it displays whole code `<a href='next.php'>this</a>` instead of **link**. I have tried assigning `href` link in php variable, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert): _"The alert dialog should be used for messages which do not require any response on the part of the user, other than the acknowledgement of the message."_ - hence it only prints text not html

Comment: Doesn't seem like much research effort went into this problem

Comment: Also note ... NEVER use `async: false,` it is a terrible practice and is deprecated. See warnings in your browser console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only display text in an `alert` function.

If you just want to redirect then you can use `window.confirm`

```js
if (window.confirm('Clicking "ok" will redirect you . Are you Sure ? ')) 
{
window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/';
};
```

or as ankit suggested you can use custom plugins like bootstrap modals or jquery ui dialog

[jQuery Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gth/L1cnqeky/)

Answer (score 2):

The `alert()` dialog is not rendered in HTML, and thus the HTML you have embedded is meaningless.

You'd need to use a custom model to achieve that